Travel Plan with Schengen visa single entry
Can I plan my trip plan < Singpaore to Amsterdam to Interlaken to Milan to Tromso to Paris to Singapore> with Schengen visa single entry?

Yes, provided there is no unusual transit between those cities.

You would enter the Schengen area at Amsterdam.
Interlaken is in Switzerland, also a Schengen member even if it is not in the EU. So that is a domestic Schengen trip unless you transit through a non-Schengen country (like the UK, Ireland, or some Balkan states).
Milan is in Italy, also a Schengen member. So that is a domestic Schengen trip unless you transit through a non-Schengen country.
Tromsø is in Norway, also a Schengen member even if it is not in the EU. Tromsø is not one of the Arctic overseas territories. So that is a domestic Schengen trip unless you transit through a non-Schengen country.
Paris is in France, also a Schengen member. So that is a domestic Schengen trip unless you transit through a non-Schengen country.
From Paris, you would leave the Schengen area.


It might be worth mentioning that the OP should avoid the UK.  You mention not leaving the Schengen area but the need to avoid a transit in the UK might not be obvious.

@badjohn, edited.
